# What is the coefficients of determination of prediction?

Tags: regression, forecasting, r-squared

I have never seen this term mentioned before. Yet this study uses it:  https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/204328/1/ifro-wp-2011-12.pdf

Is it any different than the typical R^2, i.e. coefficients of determination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are variants of the classical $R^2$.

- McElroy coefficient of determination ${R^2_M}$ measures the goodness–of–fit in a system-of-equations model(several regression equations instead of one as in the classical case)
- coefficient of determination of estimation ${R^2_e}$ is the classical $R^2$.
- coefficient of determination of prediction${R^2_p}$ is classical $R^2$ evaluated on the single observation that was omitted during LOOCV procedure.

I hope it helps!!

Comment: thank you. Could you provide any source or additional info on the coefficient of determination of prediction? (Btw, did you mean "evaluating *upon removing a single observation* during a LOCV procedure)

Comment: The paragraph "This procedure repeats the statistical analysis N times, where N is the number of observations and at"  in the paper you cited states that it uses LOOCV to facilitate the evaluation of the system of regression equations. As for the reference, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304407677900082.  Hope this helps:)